# Error when trying to install wine32 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, wine, dependencies

**I have tried to install the wine32 package on my Ubuntu laptop. This is the output I get when typing "sudo apt-get install wine32" into the terminal:**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.9) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed
init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
login : PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

**I have tried:**

- sudo apt --fix-broken install
- sudo apt-get install -f
- Checking for held packages(there didn't seem to be any)
- Removing wine64 and all wine related packages and reinstalling them
- Installing wine32 with aptitude(almost bricked my system)
- Downloading the wine32 package from pkgs.org and installing it using dpkg -i

Non of it has worked, please help.